# Transfer values between Excel buttons

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to transfer values between two Excel buttons in Excel ribbon.
e.g. click of button1  - save a value say x 
     click of button2 -  retrieve the same value x

Note : I don't want to use local storage.

Session storage & document storage do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using add-in commands, and a single "functions.js" file to drive the actions, I don't see why you couldn't store a global variable (or some localized version thereof) within functions.js to keep and pass around the values.

Comment: Follow up question on this -  Does each click of a button on the ribbon creates a separate session of its own ?

Comment: If the button is a taskpane-launching one, yes.  But the functions.js code is all running in one session.  (You can think of these sessions as separate browser windows/tabs, with the function one being invisible...)