# Delete localstorage on close of workbook

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365.
I want to delete the values stored in local storage. Is there any way do to so ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "onClose" event if that is what you're asking.

That said, if you want the values deleted anyway on closing, why not use `sessionStorage` in place of `localStorage`?

Comment: I tried with both session storage & Office.context.document.settings. I checked using vorlon that the values are indeed getting saved.However, its not retried, My scenario is as follows -   On click of Button1 on ribbon  - save to session storage  with Key X.  On Button 2 on ribbon - retrieve from session storage with Key X. PROBLEM -->Its being retrieved as null.

Comment: Yes, session storage is per the taskpane/taskpane-invocation.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771951/transfer-values-between-excel-buttons/43772016?noredirect=1#comment74926066_43772016

Comment: None of these buttons invoke a task pane. Both the buttons are on the same ribbon & both of them populate a table in different worksheets of the same workbook.  And there is only task pane which is opened by a different button altogether.